# AWS CLI in powershell for registering the node

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-cli, aws-powershell

I am creating a windows node and registering it to an already created ELB .
What is the PowerShell equivalent of this command :

```
aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer --load-balancer-name <load-balancer-name> --instances <instance-id>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Register-ELBInstanceWithLoadBalancer.

FYI, you can use Get-AWSCmdletName to do a lookup of the PowerShell cmdlet corresponding to an AWS CLI command (amongst other things):

Get-AWSCmdletName -AwsCliCommand "aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer"

(the 'aws' part of the cli command can be omitted for typing convenience).